# Should RP realm be "URN" or "urn

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, adfs

When configuring realm in ADFS, should it be "Urn" or "urn". I know the format is `urn:anything:anything`. I'm more concerned about the `urn`.

Will it work if it starts with uppercase and not lowercase?

Does it matter  as long as the same thing is configured on both SharePoint and ADFS?

Answer (score 0):

No - I normally use lower case but should work as long as both match.